# Which of these formulations is more efficient regarding the alternating optimization scheme?

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization

I want to solve a multivariate optimization problem which is the more complex form of the following:
$$\min_{A\in I,X\in J} \|Y-AX\|_F^2+\lambda \|Y-CX\|_F^2,$$
where $(Y, C, A, X)$ are matrices with appropriate sizes, and
$(I,J)$ define specific constraints on $(A,X)$, and the scalar $\lambda$ is fixed beforehand.

As a solution, I use the alternating optimization scheme as the loop of:
$$\text{1-}\quad X^*=\arg\min_{X} \|Y-A^*X\|_F^2+\lambda \|Y-CX\|_F^2$$
$$\text{2-}\quad A^*=\arg\min_{A} \|Y-AX^*\|_F^2.$$
Although the optimization converges in a limited number of steps, we can see that the second objective ($\|Y-CX\|_F^2$) is eliminated in the optimization step of $A$.

Hence, I was wondering if it'd be more efficient (regarding the convergence) if I re-formulate it as:
$$\min_{A,X} \|Y-AX\|_F^2+\lambda \|AX-CX\|_F^2,$$
which makes both objectives to be involved in the optimization loops of both of $(A,B)$:
$$\text{1-}\quad X^*=\arg\min_{X} \|Y-A^*X\|_F^2+\lambda \|A^*X-CX\|_F^2$$
$$\text{2-}\quad A^*=\arg\min_{A} \|Y-AX^*\|_F^2+\lambda \|AX^*-CX^*\|_F^2.$$

So, should the second formulation provide any additional benefit compared to the first one regarding the speed and quality of convergence? In that case, how/why?

BTW, the above is a simplified version of the real problem, so any specific solution to this problem does not necessarily applies to the original one.

Comment: how would you optimize the final formulation?

Comment: @LinAlg Alternating scheme!

Comment: How do you determine $\lambda$ in your last problem? How can you ensure that $A \in I$ and $X \in J$? My intuition is that the last problem push $X$ and $A$ toward $0$.

Comment: @Bertrand $\lambda$ is a constant which is chosen in advance. The given problem is a simplified optimization similar to the original problem i deal with, so I'm not interested in the exact solutions of the simplified one. Consider $(I,J)$ as the constraints which prevent the trivial solutions.

Comment: Generally, I want to know if such replacements work in favor of the optimization process?

Comment: I am not able to give further constructive comments as saying that the alternating scheme seems the more appealing to me: (I) replacing $A*$ obtained from (2) into the objective function (1), and $X*$ obtained from (1) into (2). (II) Then, once you converged numerically to good starting values, I would jointly minimize over $A$ and $X$ as in you very first problem.